# Differentiating Under the Integral: derivative of $ f(x) = \int_0 ^{x^2} e^{x y^2} \,dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

This problem has been giving me trouble-perhaps you can help.  I met this problem in the context of an exam, so it may be that I am on the right track and what I have done so far is as far as a grader would like to see the problem taken, but there's still a chance I'm simply not seeing how to evaluate this integral.  The problem:
Compute the derivative of the function 
$$
 f(x) = \int_{0} ^{x^2} e^{x y^2} \,dy
$$
The general rule for differentiating under the integral states that 
$$
 \frac{d}{dx} \left( \int_{a(x)} ^{b(x)} f(x,y) \,dy   \right) = \int_{a(x)} ^{b(x)} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} ( f(x,y)) \,dy + f(x,b(x)) b^\prime (x) - f(x, a(x)) a^\prime (x)
$$
In our particular case, $a(x) = 0$, $b(x) = x^2$, and $f(x,y) = x y^2$.  Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
f^\prime (x) &= \int_{0} ^{x^2} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} (e^{x y^2}) \,dy + f(x , x^2) (2x) - f(x, 0)(0) \\
 &= \int_{0} ^{x^2} y^2 e^{x y^2} \,dy + 2x e^{x^5} \\
\end{align*}
I don't see a clear way to evaluate the integral in this expression.  Do you?  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the problem is to merely compute the derivative of the function, you don't need to evaluate the integral. This integral does not have a closed form for finite $x$. See [Gaussian Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Comment: You don't need to evaluate the integral. This form is fine as it is.